# Android Xamarin bitmap size

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap

I have to use large images (about 4000x3500 pixels) and to avoid memory problem im using the lesson found on the Xamarin site to optimize the use of such images (https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/).

However the resulting bitmap seems to be bigger than the original jpeg. The jpeg is about 2MB while the bitmap size i get by AllocationByteCount is about 33000000 Bytes, is it normal ? Is there something i am missing ? (im new on mobile development).

Thank you

Comment: A JPEG is compressed.  To render it on the screen it has to be decompressed in memory.

Comment: Maybe you have done something wrong in image size. Please give us your code.

Comment: can you share your code with us?